# wpf/c# merge or embend programmatically to create a single exe

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge, net-reactor

I have an executable 'A' made by me, that acts as a runtime, and several config files + a lot of pictures + fonts (...) made by my customers for their own clients.

My customers are graphic users & no clue about programming or compiler, but need that the total app above looks as 100% made by them to their own final users.

I would like programmatically, means in another application, let's say 'B', to merge all these into a single exe so that their own customers do not see that part is made by me & have no access to the individual files.

That embending function would be integrated into 'B', which has to exist anyway as it helps to create the config files & other functions.

I saw some possibilities

- ILmerge : I read carefully a lot of posts on that in StackO. : looks
  like its functions could be accessible by another program, but not an
  option for me : no WPF & license does not permits to redistribute
  (here would be in 'B' that I give to my users)
- NET Reactor : I own it, it works OK, just the embended feature is exactly what I am
  looking for ;  but not really an option for me as it's standalone
  products, means complicated for my users & can not be integrated in my 'B'

I can I do that ? (=means the above need=just the embending function of Reactor, but Inside my own app)

Thanks a lot,

Fabrice

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, Why cant you just launch Application "B" using Process.Start

Comment: @Pankaj: looks lime my text is not clear ; sorry for that ; the question is not to lauch 'B', but for 'B' to group 'A' and many other files and to make one single executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292) tutorial on MSDN. You should be able to have all your resources files inside your .exe by following this method.

Answer (score 0):

[ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) will probably work 
in your case. It's an open-source (Apache) clone of ILMerge, and it supports WPF merging (since version 2.0.0, that's fairly new).